# MySQL commandline execution

Tags: mysql, bash, command-line

I want to know what option makes the commandline execution of MySQL, on an empty reply, print empty set.

> mysql -u root -p myPassword mytable -e "select * from names where
>   first="%andrew%"\G"

If this query returns empty set, then the commandline execution exits without printing that there was no answer. How to make it print empty set?

The verbose mode only prints the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check it in bash.

```
if [ "a$(mysql -u root -p myPassword mytable -e "select * from names where first="%andrew%"\G")" = "a" ]
then 
    echo Empty set
else
    echo Not empty set
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try -q (quick) option.

Let's see -- 1 row result:

```
$ mysql database -q -e 'select username,user_id from ... where true limit 1'
+---------------------------+----------+
| username                  | user_id  |
+---------------------------+----------+ 
| administrator             |     1111 | 
+---------------------------+----------+
```

and now empty set:

```
$ mysql database -q -e 'select username,user_id from ... where false'
+---------------------------+----------+
| username                  | user_id  |
+---------------------------+----------+
+---------------------------+----------+
```

I think it's some sort of implementation detail in mysql command due to unbuffered output. Don't be surprised if they change it in future versions.